# How to build 'ner_ontonotes_bert_mult' model from scratch

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, deeppavlov

How can I custom train the model "ner_ontonotes_bert_mult". I want to train the model with my own dataset which have some different tags. How to train the model and use it?

When I am training my model it accepting only 40 data and after that training stops automatically. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues covering your question in DeepPavlov repository:

- https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/issues/1176
- https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/issues/1044
- https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/issues/1062

You need to change `NER_PATH` in configuration file such that vocabulary (set of tags) is not re-used and model parameters from Ontonotes are not re-used also (but still model will use pre-trained weights for BERT model).

Comment: When I am training my model it accepting only 40 data and after that training stops automatically. How to resolve this.
@yurak can you please look into this error

Comment: I would recommend to ask question in DeepPavlov issues or forum, please also provide your configuration file and full logs output.